# How Do I Use The CDK Template For Testing Whether A Step Function Has Tasks With Specific Properties?

Tags: testing, aws-cdk

**Use Case:** I am current testing my CDK Step Function stacks. Whilst I've managed to test whether there is a state machine:

`it("AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine", () => template.resourceCountIs("AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine", 1));`

I would also like to test whether the state machine has a specific task, and the task has specific properties.

```js
this.intoFifoQueueTask = new SqsSendMessage(this, "Send to Queue", {
  queue: sqsStack.queueName,
  timeout: Duration.minutes(15),
  messageBody: TaskInput.fromObject({...}),
  messageGroupId: JsonPath.stringAt("$.messageGroupId"),
  integrationPattern: IntegrationPattern.WAIT_FOR_TASK_TOKEN,
  resultPath: JsonPath.stringAt("$.result"),
});
```

How do I ensure this `SqsSendMessage` task is in the Step Function? How can I check whether it is a part of the `definition`? Is testing this granually necessary?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CDK synthesizes State Machines definitions into the `DefinitionString` property, provided you are building with the CDK's state constructs.

First, [capture](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.assertions-readme.html#capturing-values) the State Machine definition:

```js
const definition = new Capture();

template.hasResourceProperties("AWS::StepFunctions::StateMachine", {
  DefinitionString: definition,
});
```

The captured template value is typically an `Fn::Join` instrinsic function object type, not a string:

```json
{ "Fn::Join": ["", ["{\"StartAt\"...."]] }
```

The [SQS optimised integration](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-sqs.html) has a synthesized resource type like `states:::sqs:sendMessage`.  Assertions are easier if you match against the stringified definition:

```js
expect(JSON.stringify(definition.asObject())).toMatch(/states:::sqs:sendMessage/);
```